# Nomrmal probability distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A nationalised bank has found that has dialy balance available in its savings accounts follows a normal distribution with a mean of rs. 500 and standard deviation of rs. 50 The percentage of saving account holders, who maintain an average dialy balance more thamln rs. 500 is......

Here. P(X>500)=?
According to origin transformation.
P(X>(500-500)/50)
Where E(x)=500 and S.D =50

P(X>0)=

1- P(-1

=1-0.3453=65.47%
But i got an incorrect answer 
Correct answer is 49.6 %

Comment: $P(X>{500-\mu\over \sigma})=P(X>0)$. What distribution does $X$ follow?

Comment: 1-P(-1<X<0) = 1- 0.3453

Comment: If we assume perfect normality, we want $\Pr(Z\gt 0)$, where $Z$ is standard normal. This is $0.5$. The answer of $49\%$ that you quote may have been obtained by a technically inappropriate continuity correction, and is not even right, continuity correction would I think yield something close to $49.6\%$.

Comment: Question has now been edited and says $49.6\%$. So they did use continuity correction, $\Pr(Z\gt 500)=1-\Pr(X\le 500)\approx 1-\Pr(Z\le (500.5-500)/50)$.

Comment: Pr(z<=(500.5-500)/50)  im not getting it..how did you write this.

Comment: This will become p(x<0.01) .

Comment: @akash You wrote $1-P(-1<X<0)$. Why a $-1$? Shouldn't it be $-\infty$?

Comment: Sir i thought . By doing so,  i'll get correct result...eg. if i want sum of numbers Which lies between 1 to infinity then how can i achieve it ... so i did sum of all no. -  numbers lies between  0 to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume *perfect normality*, then we want
$$\Pr(Z\gt (500-500)/50),$$
that is, $\Pr(Z\gt 0)$, where $Z$ is standard normal. This is exactly $0.5$, since $\Pr(Z=0)=0$. The problem said account amounts are normally distributed, so $0.5$ is the technically correct answer to the problem as stated.

But the proposed answer of $49.6\%$ indicates that they are assuming that bank accounts have an integer number of Rs. Thus they are assuming that the distribution is not really fully normal, and are using a continuity correction. The account has $\gt 500$ Rs., so $\ge 501$. The probability that $X\ge 501$ is, roughly, $1$ minus the probability that the approximating normal is $\le 500.5$. So for our approximation we use
$$1-\Pr(Z\le (500.5-500)/50).$$
We have $(500.5-500)/50=0.01$, and now the standard normal table yields $1-0.5040$.

Comment: Thank u Sir .but sir  Slightly im confuse .you have taken approximating normal is less than or equal to 500.5  then can i take less than or equal to 500.1?

Comment: It is $500.5$. This comes from the (not fully justifiable) assumption that the probability of **exactly** $500$ is approximately $\Pr(W\le 500.5)-\Pr(W\le 499.5)$, where $W$ is the normal with mean $500$ and standard deviation $50$.

Comment: @akash: In your calculation, you essentially knew that you wanted $\Pr(Z\gt 0)$. This is $1-\Pr(Z\le 0)$, and from normal tables, or symmetry, $\Pr(Z\le 0)=0.5$.